# Better way/place to store state data (listview)

Tags: android

Im relatively new to Android and im having a couple of doubts regarding lists, fragments and where to store some state data.
Im working in an example in which i have a list view and a detail view using fragments.
When i first open the app i load (from a web service) a list of items (using asyntask).
I want to "save" that list, so if i need to go back to this activity (the list) i dont need to execute again the asynctask.
Where is the better place to "save" this list? The Application object is a good place?

Then, when i click an item from the list i want to open a new activity and load the detailed data from that object.
What is the best way to pass that object to the detail activity?
Using Application object and get the selected item (using the position param from onItemSelectedListener for example) from the list (if i have a list with items in the application object)?
Make my "Item" object implement the Parcelable interface and pass the whole object whithin an intent?
Any other ideas?

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep data for good, SQLite is the right option.

If you want to cache data temporarily, the savedInstanceState Bundle is here for that. I show you an example of use with Fragment and ListView.

```
public static final String BUNDLE_CACHE = "ListFragment.BUNDLE_CACHE";

private ArrayList<ListItem> mCachedData;
private ListView mListView;
private ListItemAdapter mListAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if ((savedInstanceState != null) && savedInstanceState.containsKey(BUNDLE_CACHE)) {
        this.mCachedData = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(BUNDLE_CACHE);
    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.layout_fragment, null);

    this.mListAdapter = new ListAdapter(inflater.getContext(), 
            R.layout.item_list_topic_categories);

    this.mListView = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    this.mListView.setAdapter(this.mListAdapter);
    this.mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this.mItemClickListener);

    if (this.mCachedData == null) {
        Log.d("onCreateView", "I make the request");
        this.downloadData();
        ... // After download is finished, you put somewhere:
        this.mCachedData = downloadedData;
    } else {
        Log.d("onCreateView", "Cool, the data is cached");
        this.buildList(this.mCachedData);
    }

    return layout;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // You put the content of your list, which is this.mCachedData, in the state
    outState.getParcelableArrayList(BUNDLE_CACHE, this.mCachedData);
}
```

I also use webservices on some of my apps, and savedInstanceState is very useful for not doing again the webservice calls when I switch view between fragments.
This case is applied when the fragment view is destroyed but the fragment still exists. When the view will be created again, it will use the cached data instead of downloading again from webservices.

---

To send Parcelable to a fragment from an Activity (according the example of biovamp), you use:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putParcelable("keyName", parcelableObject);
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

Inside your fragment you use this to get your Parcelable:

```
this.getArguments().getParcelable("keyName");
```

In order to create a Parcelable, refer to this tutorial for example: http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/06/parcelable-how-to-do-that-in-android.html

Now, you said:

> Then, when i click an item from the list i want to open a new activity

So, if you still want to create a DetailsActivity from you ListFragment, you send data using the Intent:

```
ListItem item = ... // get your item data
intent.putExtra("keyItem", item);
```

And get it inside your newly created DetailsActivity by using:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras !=null) {
    ListItem value = (ListItem) extras.getParcelable("keyItem");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michel-F. In the last code i get the keyName but i need the whole "Item" object. Where is the better place to keep a list(or map) i which i will search the item with that keyName?

Comment: I edited my exemple for your Parcelable and Fragments case. I ajusted explanations about saving state.

Answer (score 0):

You should save your list in any of persistent storages (and Application is not persistent storage). SQLite database will be most suitable in your case.

Instead of creating new Activity it's better to create new Fragment, add it to activity and then call some (custom) function (`loadMyItem()` for example) with required object as a param. In such way it no need in Intent and looks more readable (and its recommended way for today)

**EXAMPLE**

Main idea is that when you do some action (clicking ListView's item, for example) on `SectionsFragment` it calls it's parent `Activity`, and it's `Activity` decides what and where should be loaded. In this example `Activity` calls `DetailFragment` to load some data inside it.

Your Activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private DetailFragment mDetailFragment;
    private SectionsFragment mSectionsFragment;

    /*initialization stuff, it's not interesting now*/

    //Section is just custom class for example - it can be whatever you want
    public void setSection(Section section){
        mDetailFragment.loadSection(section);
    }
}
```

Your SectionsFragment:

```
public class SectionsFragment extends Fragment{

    /*initialization is also skipped*/

    /**This method may be called when ListView's item is touched or somwhere else - it's doesn't matter*/
    private void setSection(Section section){
        if(!(getActivity() instanceof MainActivity))
            throw new ClassCastException("This fragment can be created only by MainActivity");
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSection(section);
    }
}
```

And your DetailFragment:

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment{

    /*initialization*/

    public void loadSection(Section section){
        //Here your fragment decides what exactly it should load
        //for this section. Maybe do some networking, or load data from database
        //whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks biovamp i understand but if i have two fragments (list and detail) how can i pass that object from to another?

Comment: @FedericoGarcía as explained on developer.android.com you should pass object through your Activity. Yes, there will be class cast (like `(MyActivity) getActivity`) but that is ok . I'll provide more explanation in my answer soon

Comment: @FedericoGarcía I've added an example